# JSF 2.0 checking by EL if components are valid inside composite component

Tags: java, jsf-2

there is an example what I want to achieve inside my JSF composite component:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{cc.attrs.value.name}" styleClass="#{(component.valid) ? 'required' : 'required invalid'}" validatorMessage="bad name" requiredMessage="name required" immediate="true" required="true">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[\p{L}' ]{2,19}$" />
    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="name" render="name testPanel" immediate="true"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText id="surname" value="#{cc.attrs.value.surname}" styleClass="#{(component.valid) ? 'required' : 'required invalid'}" validatorMessage="bad surname" requiredMessage="surname required" immediate="true" required="true">
    <f:validateRegex pattern="^[\p{L}' ]{2,19}$" />
    <f:ajax event="blur" execute="name" render="surname testPanel" immediate="true"/>
</h:inputText>

<h:panelGroup id="testPanel" styleClass="#{(!name.valid || !surname.valid) ? 'warning' : 'none'}">
    <h:message id="msgName" for="name" showSummary="true" showDetail="false" />
    <h:message id="msgSurname" for="surname" showSummary="true" showDetail="false" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

The problem is how to evaluate if name or surname are valid/invalid at the 'testPanel'. I want both messages 'msgName' and 'msgSurname' to be wrapped with styled span (html output) that would be not present if there are no error messages for 'name' or 'surname'.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bind the components to the EL scope using `binding` attribute:

```html
<h:inputText binding="#{name}" ... />
<h:inputText binding="#{surname}" ... />
```

This way your EL attempt in the `styleClass` attribute will work.

Comment: Understood :) I want to add that setting binding simply as binding="#{name}" would not work if you put multiple composite components in view. I fixed this by setting binding to #{cc.name} (also you need to have proper field in component's UINamingcontainer class)